# XSL: How to get all textpieces, keep the order and apply certain templates within

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

following code:

```
<elem1> This is an example text
<elem2> and i want to select all of this
<elem3> and apply a template on elem3 </elem3>
<elem3> so it gets bold </elem3>
exampletext </elem2>
exampletext  </elem1>
```

The output should look like:

```
This is an example text and i want to select all of this <b>and apply a template on elem3</b><b> so it gets bold </b> exampletext exampletext
```

How can I do this with xsl?
If I use 'text()' or select'.' while looping through every element with for-each select="*" I get some of the text many times. How do I archive the outcome I wrote earlier? Even if I do a template for every element I don't know how to get the text only of this node and not of the child. And it should also stay in the same order, so I want the part of text before I enter a child node and so on...

It may be a dumb question, but im new and im desperate about that :/

Comment: You question shows you want HTML output, but you have tagged this xsl-fo. Can you confirm you do indeed want HTML output here? Also, can you post the XSLT you have tried please? It is usually easier to fix broken XSLT than for someone to write it from scratch. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use XSLT's default recursive [processing model](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Processing-Model). For example, the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="elem3">
    <b>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </b>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will copy all text nodes (using the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule)) and add a `<b>` wrapper around those  contained in `elem3` elements, to return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 This is an example text
 and i want to select all of this
<b> and apply a template on elem3 </b><b> so it gets bold </b>
exampletext 
exampletext
```

If you prefer, you could add:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
   <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
</xsl:template>
```

and get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
This is an example textand i want to select all of this<b>and apply a template on elem3</b><b>so it gets bold</b>exampletextexampletext
```